# Converting from base-10 to word

Tags: algorithm, c

The following code is used to convert a base-10 number to a base-N number, where `N` is a length of a given alphabet that contains characters of which a base-N number can consist.

The number to convert is always increasing, like from 1 to 45789, not from 536 to 13. The resulting number may not contain zero as first digit, so I need to *carry the one*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long ull;

void conv(ull num, const char *alpha, char *word, int base){
    while (num) {
       *(word++)=alpha[(num-1)%base];
       num=(num-1)/base;
    }
}

int main(){
   ull nu;
   const char alpha[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzOSR34"; 

   /* "OSR43" was added to show that the letters of alpha
      are NOT in alphabetical order */

   char *word=calloc(30,sizeof(char));
   // word always contains null-terminator
   int base=(int)strlen(alpha);
   for (nu=1;nu<=1e8;++nu) {
       conv(nu,alpha,word,base);
       printf("%s\n",word);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This code's working fine but I need to speed it up *as much as possible*. How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Improving `conv`

To convert a base-10 number to base-N, I don't think it gets faster than the `conv` function your wrote. I would write it a bit differently though:

```
void toBaseN(ull num, const char *alpha, int base, char *word) {
    while (num) {
       *(word++) = alpha[(num - 1) % base];
       num = (num - 1) / base;
    }
}
```

What I changed:

- Renamed the function: `conv` doesn't describe what it does
- Rearranged the parameters: `base` is tightly related to `alpha` (the length), and I think it's good to have out-parameters as last
- Add spaces around the operators to improve readability

For the record, this function doesn't return what I would expect.
It returns the digits in reverse order, which is a bit odd.
For example with the given alphabet,
it returns `ba` for `33` and `ca` for `34`, when I would expect `ab` and `ac`, respectively.

The function has a number expectations with regards to the input:

- `word` is expected to be big enough to contain the digits
- `word` is expected to be filled with nulls
- `base` is expected to be the length of `alpha`

The first one is reasonable and quite natural,
the others are not, and should be documented in a comment above the function.

#### Improving `main`

> ```
> const char alpha[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzOSR34"; 
> char *word=calloc(30,sizeof(char));
> // word always contains null-terminator
> int base=(int)strlen(alpha);
> for (nu=1;nu<=1e8;++nu) {
> ```

There are a couple of things I don't like about this bit:

- Too packed code: add more spaces around operators like I did in the previous point
- The comment `// word always contains null-terminator` seems misplaced. It seems you intended it for the line above it. It's more intuitive and readable to have comments above the line they refer to. The make it even more clear, it would be good to leave a blank line before the comment, and perhaps even after the statement
- What is magic number 30? It would be better to make this a global constant
- `base` is derived from `alpha`, it's tightly related, so I'd move these closer to each other

I suggest this writing style:

```
const char alpha[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzOSR34";
int base = (int) strlen(alpha);

// word always contains null-terminator
char *word = calloc(30, sizeof(char));

for (nu = 1; nu <= 1e8; ++nu) {
```

#### Improving speed

As I mentioned above, the general functionality of `conv` without a context is as fast as it can be. (And incorrect: normally I'd expect digits to be reversed.)

In the context of printing base-N numbers within the range `[start : end]`,
you can do better.
You could convert `start` and `end` to base-N,
to do the counting in base-N.
This will be significantly faster than counting in base-10 and converting in every step.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The only think I want to clarify: how do I do _counting_ in base-N? I've been struggling with it for a long time but the only solution I found is to overload `operator+` in C++, but I need C.

Comment: For example if you have `abc`, the next number is `abd`.  Just use the next digit in the alphabet. The tricky part is handling the overflows, for example if you have `b444` (using your alphabet), then the next number will be `caaa`. You don't need C++ here at all, this is plain math.

Answer (score 4):

## Typedef

I like to avoid typedefs without semantic meaning. In other words, `ull` is just a shortcut for `unsigned long long`, not a meaningful type.

I'm assuming you care you about the maximum value more than you care that the type is specifically an `unsigned long long`, so I would use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h` instead of your typedef.

If you *are* going to use a typedef, try to give it a more meaningful name (which is pretty difficult in this situation without resorting to a pretty vague name like `number` or something).

---

## `while` vs `for`

This is more of a personal style thing, but I tend to use `for` loops over `while` loops whenever reasonable:

```
for (; num > 0; num = (num - 1) / base) {
    *(word++) = alpha[(num - 1) % base];
}
```

Depending on how much you want to cram into the `for` loop (it can definitely go too far), you could even take it a step farther so that the `for` handles all of the iteration type stuff:

```
for (; num > 0; num = (num - 1) / base, ++word) {
    *word = alpha[(num - 1) % base];
}
```

---

## Variable declaration

It looks like you're using C99 or newer, so `nu` doesn't need to be declared at the top of `main`. Instead, declare it in the tightest scope at the closest place to initial usage possible. In other words, `nu` should be declared in the for loop in which its used (`for (ull nu = 0; ...; ...)`).

---

## Comments

These are both super minor:

```
/* "OSR43" was added to show that the letters of alpha
  are NOT in alphabetical order */
```

`alpha` has `OSR34` in it not `OSR43`.

```
// word always contains null-terminator
```

I would put this inside of the loop instead of under `calloc` since I'm assuming the meaning is something like "Since `word` never decreases in length, it's always null terminated." Seeing it under `calloc` made my first thought "well of course a `calloc` allocated string is null terminated!" before realizing what you really meant.

---

## sizeof

It's kind of iffy in situations this simple, but I like to use `sizeof` on the thing it's involved with instead of a type. In other words, I would have done `char *word = calloc(30, sizeof(*word));`. It looks a bit stupid in the simple case, but in complex code, it can be quite nice since it's impossible to change the type of the variable and forget to change the `sizeof`. It's kind of a DRY manifestation of sorts.

---

## Performance

> This code's working fine but I need to speed it up as much as possible. How do I do it?

I'm not much an optimization expert, so perhaps someone will come along with some magic, but as far as I can tell, `conv` isn't going to get meaningfully faster than it already is.

There is, fortunately a trivial 'optimization' is available with the output. In particular, `puts`, though simpler (`puts(s)` is equivalent to `printf("%s\n", s)`), is much faster than `printf`. Changing from `printf` to `puts` cuts the time the program takes to run on my computer from 8 seconds to 2.75 seconds.